# Evaluate infinite sum involving n!

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n×n!}$

I really don't know where to begin with this but I'm pretty sure $e$ is involved somehow.

If it can help, $n×n!=(n+1)!-n!$

Comment: It's $\int_0^1\frac{e^x-1}{x}\,dx$....but what is that?

Comment: Quite so: the best Mathematica can come up with is `ExpIntegralEi[1] - EulerGamma`.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Risch's says nothing about the definite integral. The value could be a rational multiple of $\pi$ for all we know. It is just not known. "Therefore, your answer is not available in closed form..." is not a valid implication.

Comment: @YAlexandrov Yes, that is correct. It will only tell you that the indefinite integral does not have a closed form, so you  are right.

Comment: [It converges very fast](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2ujtj04hwe) to around $1.318$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have
$$
\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,\,n} {\;{1 \over {n \cdot n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,n} {\;{1 \over {\left( {n + 1} \right) \cdot \left( {n + 1} \right)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,n} {\;{1 \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)^2  \cdot n!}}} 
$$

Then, starting from the series of $e^x$, we get
$$
\eqalign{
  & e^{\,x}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,n} {\;{{x^n } \over {n!}}}   \cr 
  & \int_0^x {e^{\,u} du}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,n} {\;{{x^{n + 1} } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)n!}}}   \cr 
  & {1 \over x}\int_0^x {e^{\,t} dt}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,n} {\;{{x^n } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)n!}}}   \cr 
  & \int_0^x {{1 \over u}\left( {\int_0^u {e^{\,t} dt} } \right)du}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,n} {\;{{x^{n + 1} } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)^2  \cdot n!}}}   \cr 
  & {1 \over x}\int_0^x {{1 \over u}\left( {\int_0^u {e^{\,t} dt} } \right)du}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\,n} {\;{{x^n } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)^2  \cdot n!}}}  \cr} 
$$

so that
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(x) = \sum_{0\, \le \,n} {{x^n \over {(n + 1)^2  \cdot n!}}}  = {1 \over x} \int_0^x {1 \over u}\left( \int_0^u {e^t \, dt } \right) \, du  = {1 \over x} \int_0^x {e^u - 1 \over u} \, du  = \cr 
  &  = {1 \over x} \left( -\ln x + \operatorname{Ei}(x) - \lim_{t\;\to\;0+} \left( -\ln t + \operatorname{Ei}(t) \right) \right) = \cr
  &  = {1 \over x} \left( -\ln x + \operatorname{E}_1 (x) + \lim_{t\; \to \;0+} (\ln t - \operatorname{E}_1 (t)) \right) \cr} 
$$
Note that the integrand function $(e^u - 1)/ u$ is continuous ( $\lim\limits_{x\; \to \;0} ( (e^x - 1)/x) = 1$ )
and positive.
The Exponential Integral function is  [as in MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html):
$$
\operatorname{Ei}(x) = -\int_{-x}^\infty  {{e^{-u} \over u} \, du = \int_{-\infty }^x {e^u \over u} \, du  = \gamma  + \ln x + \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,\,n} {x^n \over n \cdot n!}} 
$$

So we can conclude that
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,\,n} {\;{1 \over {n \cdot n!}}}  = \int_0^1 {{{e^{\,u}  - 1} \over u}du}  = {\rm Ei}(1) - \gamma  \approx 1.3179
}$$

Comment: This was an extreme case of lots of purposeless complication in the MathJax code, including `\;{{x^{\,\,n} }` where `x^n` would serve, and some things even more absurd.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: that's because I am using TexAide to compose the formulas, put them onto a spreadsheet, and write my notes on the subject. But the pictures on the spreadsheet are rendered with too a narrow spacing, and I'm compelled to enlarge them . Did not expect that the mathjax formulation was of interest, sorry.

Comment: The problem is that some people learn how to use MathJax by looking at MathJax code they see here, and that's not a bad way to do it when the code is written well.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

$$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

And also

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a_nx^n}{n}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n\int_0^x t^{n-1}dt$$